# SELECT statement with duplicate table names

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates

I have two different functioning sql statements that need to be combined.

Trying to avoid duplicate names in a SELECT statement while still retrieving the data I'm looking for in a SQL query.

First longer query:

```
Select USER.USER_NAME, ASSET.NAME AS KACE_ASSET_NAME, FIELD_31, V3.FIELD_VALUE AS CUSTOM_3, FIELD_20 AS BARCODE, FIELD_27 AS SERIAL_NUMBER

FROM ASSET
JOIN USER ON ASSET.OWNER_ID = USER.ID

JOIN ASSET_DATA_5 ON ASSET.ASSET_DATA_ID = ASSET_DATA_5.ID AND ASSET_TYPE_ID = 5


LEFT JOIN USER_FIELD_VALUE V3 ON V3.USER_ID = USER.ID AND V3.FIELD_ID = 3 

LEFT JOIN ASSET ASSET_LOCATION  ON ASSET_LOCATION.ID = ASSET.LOCATION_ID
LEFT JOIN ASSET_ASSOCIATION J21 ON J21.ASSET_ID = ASSET.ID AND J21.ASSET_FIELD_ID=21
LEFT JOIN ASSET A21 ON A21.ID = J21.ASSOCIATED_ASSET_ID
LEFT JOIN ASSET_DATA_1 AD21 ON AD21.ID = A21.ASSET_DATA_ID
WHERE V3.FIELD_VALUE = 'TERMINATED'
```

Second smaller query:

```
SELECT ASSET.NAME AS CITY 
FROM ASSET_DATA_1 LEFT JOIN ASSET ON ASSET_DATA_1.ID = ASSET.ASSET_DATA_ID AND ASSET.ASSET_TYPE_ID=1
```

My best effort to combine the two:

```
Select USER.USER_NAME, ASSET.NAME AS KACE_ASSET_NAME, FIELD_31, V3.FIELD_VALUE AS CUSTOM_3, FIELD_20 AS BARCODE, FIELD_27 AS SERIAL_NUMBER, ASSET.NAME as CITY

FROM ASSET
JOIN USER ON ASSET.OWNER_ID = USER.ID

JOIN ASSET_DATA_5 ON ASSET.ASSET_DATA_ID = ASSET_DATA_5.ID AND ASSET_TYPE_ID = 5


LEFT JOIN USER_FIELD_VALUE V3 ON V3.USER_ID = USER.ID AND V3.FIELD_ID = 3 

LEFT JOIN ASSET ASSET_LOCATION  ON ASSET_LOCATION.ID = ASSET.LOCATION_ID
LEFT JOIN ASSET_ASSOCIATION J21 ON J21.ASSET_ID = ASSET.ID AND J21.ASSET_FIELD_ID=21
LEFT JOIN ASSET A21 ON A21.ID = J21.ASSOCIATED_ASSET_ID
LEFT JOIN ASSET_DATA_1 AD21 ON AD21.ID = A21.ASSET_DATA_ID


#IMPORTANT JOIN HERE - NEED TO LINK THIS INFO BACK TO SELECT STATEMENT
LEFT JOIN ASSET ASSET_DATA_1 ON ASSET_DATA_1.ID = ASSET.ASSET_DATA_ID AND ASSET.ASSET_TYPE_ID=1  


WHERE V3.FIELD_VALUE = 'TERMINATED'
```

So trying to structure this SELECT statement so that asset.name is correctly linked back to the last LEFT JOIN listed here. Issue is that there are two columns named ASSET.NAME and two ASSET tables, I believe. I'm not sure how to call "ASSET.NAME" data from the "ASSET_DATA_1" table in the SELECT statement without just getting a duplicate of the first Asset table. 
I've looked around for answers and have tried things like SELECT statements in parentheses and UNION commands but neither of those seem to be the answer. SQL noob and feeling a little overwhelmed with this one.

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates use a group by on all the selected columns.

```
SELECT USER.USER_NAME, ASSET.NAME AS KACE_ASSET_NAME, FIELD_31, V3.FIELD_VALUE AS CUSTOM_3, FIELD_20 AS BARCODE, FIELD_27 AS SERIAL_NUMBER
FROM ASSET
JOIN USER ON ASSET.OWNER_ID = USER.ID
JOIN ASSET_DATA_5 ON ASSET.ASSET_DATA_ID = ASSET_DATA_5.ID AND ASSET_TYPE_ID = 5
LEFT JOIN USER_FIELD_VALUE V3 ON V3.USER_ID = USER.ID AND V3.FIELD_ID = 3 
LEFT JOIN ASSET ASSET_LOCATION  ON ASSET_LOCATION.ID = ASSET.LOCATION_ID
LEFT JOIN ASSET_ASSOCIATION J21 ON J21.ASSET_ID = ASSET.ID AND J21.ASSET_FIELD_ID=21
LEFT JOIN ASSET A21 ON A21.ID = J21.ASSOCIATED_ASSET_ID
LEFT JOIN ASSET_DATA_1 AD21 ON AD21.ID = A21.ASSET_DATA_ID
WHERE V3.FIELD_VALUE = 'TERMINATED'
GROUP BY USER.USER_NAME, ASSET.NAME, FIELD_31, V3.FIELD_VALUE, FIELD_20, FIELD_27;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want remove duplicated  rows   you should use DISTINCT clause

```
Select DISTINCT 

    USER.USER_NAME, ASSET.NAME AS KACE_ASSET_NAME, FIELD_31,
     V3.FIELD_VALUE AS CUSTOM_3, FIELD_20 AS BARCODE, FIELD_27 AS SERIAL_NUMBER

FROM ASSET
JOIN USER ON ASSET.OWNER_ID = USER.ID

JOIN ASSET_DATA_5 ON ASSET.ASSET_DATA_ID = ASSET_DATA_5.ID AND ASSET_TYPE_ID = 5


LEFT JOIN USER_FIELD_VALUE V3 ON V3.USER_ID = USER.ID AND V3.FIELD_ID = 3 

LEFT JOIN ASSET ASSET_LOCATION  ON ASSET_LOCATION.ID = ASSET.LOCATION_ID
LEFT JOIN ASSET_ASSOCIATION J21 ON J21.ASSET_ID = ASSET.ID AND J21.ASSET_FIELD_ID=21
LEFT JOIN ASSET A21 ON A21.ID = J21.ASSOCIATED_ASSET_ID
LEFT JOIN ASSET_DATA_1 AD21 ON AD21.ID = A21.ASSET_DATA_ID
WHERE V3.FIELD_VALUE = 'TERMINATED'
```

(the use of group by for this scope when you have not aggregation function is deprecated  in sql and in the most recent version of mysql is not allowed)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a different alias for the second copy of the asset table:

```
Select USER.USER_NAME, 
ASSET.NAME AS KACE_ASSET_NAME, 
FIELD_31, 
V3.FIELD_VALUE AS CUSTOM_3, 
FIELD_20 AS BARCODE, 
FIELD_27 AS SERIAL_NUMBER,
 asset_again .NAME as CITY

FROM ASSET
JOIN USER ON ASSET.OWNER_ID = USER.ID

JOIN ASSET_DATA_5 ON ASSET.ASSET_DATA_ID = ASSET_DATA_5.ID AND ASSET_TYPE_ID = 5


LEFT JOIN USER_FIELD_VALUE V3 ON V3.USER_ID = USER.ID AND V3.FIELD_ID = 3 

LEFT JOIN ASSET ASSET_LOCATION  ON ASSET_LOCATION.ID = ASSET.LOCATION_ID
LEFT JOIN ASSET_ASSOCIATION J21 ON J21.ASSET_ID = ASSET.ID AND J21.ASSET_FIELD_ID=21
LEFT JOIN ASSET A21 ON A21.ID = J21.ASSOCIATED_ASSET_ID
LEFT JOIN ASSET_DATA_1 AD21 ON AD21.ID = A21.ASSET_DATA_ID


#IMPORTANT JOIN HERE - NEED TO LINK THIS INFO BACK TO SELECT STATEMENT
LEFT JOIN ASSET asset_again ON ad21 .ID = asset_again.ASSET_DATA_ID AND asset_again .ASSET_TYPE_ID=1  


WHERE V3.FIELD_VALUE = 'TERMINATED'
```

In fact,  reading the question again i see you try to but confuse things by using ASSET_DATA_1 as the alias. Use a unique (to the query) alias and use that alias to refer to the table in the columns list